# MS Word VBA Macro to find text, use text to download an image, and replace the text with the image

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've been trying to get a macro going that lets me do the following:

1. Find a SMILES (chemistry) sequence that is wrapped in "///" at the front and "////" at the back and inside of a 1 cell table in a word document
2. Use that sequence as a search entry for an online chemical structure generator
3. Download the generated image and Replace SMILES sequence text with the image
4. Repeat this for all other sequences in the Document

Here is what I have so far. This lets me replace the SMILES with the picture. I just need it to repeat/loop until there is no more finds.

```html
Sub Macro()
'Find a SMILES string between "///" and "////"
    With ActiveDocument
        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting

        With Selection.Find
            .Text = "///*////"
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchWildcards = True
        End With
        If Selection.Find.Execute Then
'Use found term as a search string for the online structure generator
        Dim name As String
        name = Selection.Range.Text
        Dim imgURL As String
        Dim XMLhttp: Set XMLhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        XMLhttp.setTimeouts 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000
        imgURL = "http://cactus.nci.nih.gov/chemical/structure/" + name + "/image"
        XMLhttp.Open "GET", imgURL, False
        XMLhttp.send
        If XMLhttp.Status = 200 Then
'It exists so get the image
        ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=imgURL, _
    LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Range:=Selection.Range
'Resize
With .InlineShapes(1)
    'this will convert to 'in front of text'
    .ConvertToShape
    'this will keep ratio
    .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
    'this will adjust width to 2.0 inch
    .Width = InchesToPoints(2#)
End With
Selection.Range.Delete
        End If
        End If
 End With
 End Sub
```

And an example of the macro result [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Bvi1.png).
I would greatly appreciate any help.

edit: example SMILES sequence   CCC1(C(=O)NCNC1=O)C1=CC=CC=C1 and [generated image for example structure](https://cactus.nci.nih.gov/chemical/structure/CCC1(C(=O)NCNC1=O)C1=CC=CC=C1/image)
edit2: updated with progress

Comment: What happens when you run that?

Comment: The first search results for "///*////" is highlighted, then nothing. The document picture in the post is a snapshot after running this macro. The appropriate sequence is highlighted but I'm not sure where the issue lies. That is to say, I don't know if I have properly set the imgURL name to be what the search found or if the macro is not properly downloading/adding the image.

Comment: Sorry - I commented before reading the code.  You need to grab `Selection.text`, replace the slashes, then use that for `Name` In the URL

Comment: I think the slashes are okay because the structure generator will still produce the correct structure even if they are included. But yeah, I need to figure out how to use the find result as a "name" for the url.

Comment: In that case just use `Selection.Text` in place of `Name`

Comment: Thanks, that sent me in the right direction! I'll just need to figure out how to loop it now. I'll post what I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notes:

- Moved the Search code to a separate function for more flexibility (code re-use!)
- You should use HEAD in place of GET if you only want the HTTP status result: no point in asking for a full response if you don't need it...

Code:

```
Sub SmilesToImage()
    Const URL As String = "http://cactus.nci.nih.gov/chemical/structure/{smiles}/image"

    Dim smiles As String, colMatches As Collection, m As Range, imgUrl

    Set colMatches = GetMatches(ActiveDocument, "///*////")

    If colMatches.Count > 0 Then
        Dim XMLhttp: Set XMLhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        For Each m In colMatches
            Debug.Print m.Text
            imgUrl = Replace(URL, "{smiles}", m.Text)
            XMLhttp.Open "HEAD", imgUrl, False '<<< use HEAD as you only need the status result
            XMLhttp.send
            If XMLhttp.Status = 200 Then
                'm.Text = "" '<< uncomment if you want to remove the SMILES
                ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=imgUrl, _
                    LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Range:=m
            End If
        Next m
    End If
End Sub

 'Get a collection of Ranges matching the passed search pattern
 Function GetMatches(doc As Document, sPattern As String)
    Dim rv As New Collection, rng As Range
    Set rng = doc.Range
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Forward = True
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Text = sPattern
        Do While .Execute
            rv.Add doc.Range(rng.Start, rng.End)
            rng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With
    Set GetMatches = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, that quickly goes through and converts them! The original size is a bit too big for the index card template and the find results seem to not get deleted. Adding ".ConvertToShape", .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue, and ".Width = InchesToPoints(2#)" seems to work for resize, but I couldn't figure out how to delete the find results. I think I will just end up changing the smiles text into white color to make them invisible. Thanks again :)

Comment: If you uncomment the indicated line it will remove the smiles string

Comment: My apologies, I totally missed that! The code works wonderfully, thank you again.